# Send terminal command through Pyserial ascii format

Tags: python, ascii, pyserial

I would like to create a Python programm like a terminal to send some request with Pyserial.

But when I send a request like "dataid 60000 get value" it show me an error message like :
TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: 'dataid 60000 get value'

I tried to use .encode but no result..

See below my code :

```
#Modules
from base64 import encode
import serial

port = "COM5"
baud = 115200

#Serial port configuration
com = serial.Serial(port, baud, timeout=1)

if com.isOpen():
    print(com.name + ' is open...')

#Print output
while True:
    cmd = input("Enter command or 'exit':")
    if cmd == 'exit':
        com.close()
        exit()
    else:
        com.write(cmd)
        out = com.read()
        print('Receiving...'+out)
```

Thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1):

To send command over serial/console port, use:
`com.write(cmd.encode("utf-8"))`
or 
`com.write(b"string")`

This encodes your input to bytes.